# Error while deploying a static website in heroku

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can not deploy a simple website which have just HTML and CSS code in heroku. Also, I have another website where I have used HTML, CSS, Javscript and Bootstrap.

The error message is:
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)

Comment: Please share more details. That's not a common error message for Javascript, HTML, or CSS

Comment: That's a git hook error message, but you've left out all the details that might give us a clue about what the problem is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You may have the branch restrictions in the master branch of you git repository. You need to check the repository settings of your git and then check branch permissions.
If there is no one who have write access in your repository, then add the user and try again deploying the website.